# js ctrlKey in onkeyUp event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following js function:

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2hqgubw/3/)

```
<script>
    function functionKeyUp(event){
      var val = event.keyCode;              
      var ctrl = [65,97] //a or A

      console.log("keycode: " + val);

      if(event.ctrlKey && (ctrl.indexOf(val) > -1)){ //When both ctrl + A is clicked
           console.log("Ctrl+ A success");
           $('.result').text("Ctrl + A is clicked");

      }else{
           console.log("Ctrl+ A fail");
           $('.result').text("Didn't recognize it");
      }                                                 
 };
</script>

<div type="text" class="example" onkeyUp="functionKeyUp(event);"  contentEditable="true">
  Try ctrl + a
</div>

<div class="result">

</div>
```

When `ctrl + a` is clicked, it recognizes two inputs as separate and not as one key.

How would I go about so that it recognizes `ctrl + a` together?

Comment: Record both key presses and test for both on each press.

Comment: `ctrl` and `a` are registered separately even though I clicked them together. You can see by the element inspect for the `console.log("keycode: " + val);`

Comment: You could keep track of each key press in some container external to the handler, and whenever a key is pressed, check if the other key is pressed as well.

Comment: ah I see what you mean. Like a trigger. Okay. So from the sound of it, there is no specific way to recognize two keys together.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've written JS, so I can't remember specifically. If there was a way, `ctrl` would be considered a special key, and would be recorded somewhere in the event object separately. In cases like this, I use something like a set, and whenever a key is pressed, I add it to the set, and when it's released, I remove it. Then in the handler you just check if both keys are in the set. Of course this abuses a global state, but there's ways of making it "safer". It's 11pm here, and I'm on my way to be though after work, and my brain feels fried.

Comment: An example might have to wait until tomorrow if you need one (went over the character limit on the previous comment).

Comment: Haha i see. Thanks!  I think that's a good start for me. Should be able to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Definitely look at the docs for the event object though.

Comment: Will sure do! Good night

Comment: http://mobile.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/events-and-javascript-part-3-the-event-object.html. Of note is the `ctrlKey` property of the object. And thanks.